# box-shadow inset on <html> works just in the viewable part of the website

Tags: html, browser, css

I use `box-shadow` on the `html` element to give the background of a website a light vignette effect. But if the content of the site is longer than the window the `box-shadow` will only display in the part of the site which is viewable at the first glance. If you scroll down, the `box-shadow` stops working.

Here is my CSS code:

```
html {
    box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;    
    margin: 0;
    background: url('../img/subtle_grunge.png');
}
```

I tried to apply the `box-shadow` to the `body` element, but that won't work either. Surprisingly the background-image set for the `body` works just fine. The problem appears in all browsers (Safari 6, Firefox 18, Chrome 24 – all on Mac).
Is there a solution?

Here is a example: http://dreamapp.de/sites/portfolio/boxshadowproblem.html

[image]

Comment: have you tried `min-height:100%`? Or just removing it all together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a `<div>` right after the `<body>` tag and move to it the CSS properties. Such as:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="vignette"></div>
  <!-- rest of your code -->
```

**CSS**

```
.vignette {
  position: fixed;
  /* to prevent empty space around the vignette */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* extends to the whole visible area */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset;
}
```

in this way the element will stay under all the other elements and you can scroll the content.

Comment: Awesome! This works like a charm! …and it's so easy! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "height: 100%;" style from your html tag. Alternatively, you can change it to "min-height: 100%;"

Comment: Sadly that wont work. If I do that the `box-shadow` will only display in those areas where the body is. If the body is shorter than the window the box-shadow stops at the end of the body. Strangely the background-image, defined in the body is displayed on the whole side...

Answer (score 0):

i find this to be more consistent no matter the Page's dimensions

```css
.vignette {
    min-height: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

and to use it i prefer adding it to the html tag

```html
<html class="vignette">
<!-- your site here -->
</html>
```